# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string cant solve

Tags: javascript

I have an error that i cant find the answer to.
Here's the code:

```js
function randomColor(){
    const r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    const g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    const b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    return rgb'(' + r + ',' + g + ',' + b ')'
  }
```

Comment: Just use  `'rgb(' + r + ',' + g + ',' + b + ')';`, sample of concatination

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include the `+` after b, as `)` also has to be concatenated to the main string

```js
function randomColor() {
  const r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
  const g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
  const b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);

  return 'rgb(' + r + ',' + g + ',' + b + ')';
}
console.log(randomColor())
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the below code

```js
function randomColor(){
    const r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    const g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    const b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    return ["rgb(",r,",",g,",",b,")"].join("");
  }
  
  console.log(randomColor());
```